# Why does '%d-%m-%Y' format return always NULL?

Tags: sqlite

I have dates in this format `31/01/1970` or `%d/%m/%Y`.

This expression returns `NULL`

```
SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y','31/01/1970')
```

I thought it might have been a problem with the `/` character but also

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y','31-01-1970')
```

returns `NULL`.

The only expression that seems to work is

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d','1970-01-31')
```

Why?

PS: Actually from the sqlite3 console I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand how `strftime` works. [`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) expects its time argument to be in ISO8601 format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD for a date) and then it formats that time using the format string.

`strftime` isn't for parsing dates and times, it is for formatting them.

If you want to parse `'31/01/1970'` into a format that SQLite can work with then you're stuck with `substr`:

```
select substr('31/01/1970', 7, 4) || '-' || substr('31/01/1970', 4, 2) || '-' ||  substr('31/01/1970', 1, 2);
```

and then you could feed that string into `strftime` to format it:

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', substr('31/01/1970', 7, 4) || '-' || substr('31/01/1970', 4, 2) || '-' ||  substr('31/01/1970', 1, 2));
```